# Can Monks Unarmed Strike be used as a basic attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, unarmed-combat

I know there are a ton of monk questions and I read as many as I thought might apply but I'm still not sure I understand.

First, I am wondering if you can use your Monk Unarmed Strike as a basic attack? It is defined as a weapon in the unarmed category so I'm wondering if it can be used as my weapon. For role-play purposes I don't want to wield or use any weapons so I plan to only use unarmed attacks. So if I make a melee basic attack can I use my monk unarmed strike as the weapon? That is to say would I roll 1d4 or 1d8 for basic unarmed melee attacks?

Additionally, would the bonus attack be triggered if I were to use the monk unarmed strike as a weapon?

Finally, is there a way to negate attacks of opportunity against me when I make unarmed attacks?

Answer (score 5):

**Monk Unarmed Strike is a weapon** As a weapon, you can use it with any weapon power, including a Melee Basic Attack.

Note, however, that Melee Basic Attack uses Strength for its attack and damage rolls, unless you take a feat or item that allows you to use Dexterity instead.

Note also that you cannot enchant your fists -- but you can use the enhancement bonus of a Ki focus to empower your Monk Unarmed Strike attacks.

Unarmed attacks do not grant enemies attacks of opportunity in 4th edition, so that's a non-issue.

Comment: To add to this you can also take the monk feat Internalize the Basic Kata, published in dragon mag 404, which allows you to use your dexterity in place of your strength when making MBAs and even allows you to use your flurry of blows when hitting with an opportunity attack. Improved Monk Unarmed Strike, a feat published in player's handbook 3, can increase your fists weapon die from a d8 to a d10 (Note:this doesn't change the die with implement attacks that the monk uses)